# plotly.js excessive white space between legend anc chart

Tags: plotly, plotly.js

having a plotly chart made of two y-axis, I get a legend which is kind of far away from the chart elements. 
I can set it closer using "x" and "y" coordinates, but this clashes with different screen sizes, where it looks good on full hd but on lower resolutions, the legend might overlap the bar chart itself.

[image: Example]

Comment: It would help if you provided a jsFiddle for your question.

Answer (score 0):

The margins around the plot can be controlled using the margin object on layout.

For example:

```
var layout = {
  ...
  margin: {
    l: 50,
    r: 50,
    b: 100,
    t: 100,
    pad: 4
  }
  ...
};
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

https://plotly.com/javascript/setting-graph-size/